# How to combine multiple pandas data frames that are the same size into one cohesive database?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to build a database with various pandas data frames that are the same size. I want to assign each point in the data frame with all of the other points.

Such that I get something like this:

Data frame 1:

```
   1  2  3  4  
 1 A  B  C  D  
 2 A  B  C  D  
 3 A  B  C  D
```

Data frame 2:

```
   1  2  3  4  
 1 A  D  G  J
 2 B  E  H  K
 3 C  F  I  L
```

Final Data Frame (something like this)

```
     1     2     3     4
 1 [A,A] [B,D] [C,G] [D,J]
 2 [A,B] [B,E] [C,H] [D,K]
 3 [A,C] [B,F] [C,I] [D,L]
```

Comment: Is it necessary to store the combined `Frames` as lists? Typically you try to avoid such things.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the values from both dataframes, plus a separator in between, and iterate over the columns using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to create lists. Finally use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) to turn the result into a dataframe:

```
df = df1 + ',' + df2
pd.concat([df[col].str.split(',') for col in df.columns], axis=1)

     1       2       3       4
1  [A, A]  [B, D]  [C, G]  [D, J]
2  [A, B]  [B, E]  [C, H]  [D, K]
3  [A, C]  [B, F]  [C, I]  [D, L]
```

Or using [`DataFrame.combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html):

```
df1.combine(df2, func=lambda a,b: (a + ',' + b).str.split(','))

     1       2       3       4
1  [A, A]  [B, D]  [C, G]  [D, J]
2  [A, B]  [B, E]  [C, H]  [D, K]
3  [A, C]  [B, F]  [C, I]  [D, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],1).groupby(level=0,axis=1).agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist())
Out[529]: 
        1       2       3       4
1  [A, A]  [B, D]  [C, G]  [D, J]
2  [A, B]  [B, E]  [C, H]  [D, K]
3  [A, C]  [B, F]  [C, I]  [D, L]
```

If I were you I will look at multiple index rather than list type columns

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],1,keys=[1,2])
Out[530]: 
   1           2         
   1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4
1  A  B  C  D  A  D  G  J
2  A  B  C  D  B  E  H  K
3  A  B  C  D  C  F  I  L
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but you can convert all cells to lists and then simply add the dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [list('ABCD') for _ in range(5)]
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=4).tolist() for _ in range(5)]
)

df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: [[v] for v in x])
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: [[v] for v in x])

df1 + df2
```

which outputs

```
        0       1       2       3
0  [A, C]  [B, D]  [C, A]  [D, C]
1  [A, C]  [B, D]  [C, A]  [D, A]
2  [A, C]  [B, B]  [C, C]  [D, C]
3  [A, C]  [B, C]  [C, D]  [D, A]
4  [A, D]  [B, D]  [C, D]  [D, C]
```